# How to modify a record displaying a form in a view

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to accomplish the following:

I have a list of fruits, that are stored in a table with two columns "id", "name" and "color".
Next to each fruit, I got a "modify" button. What I want to do here is being able to display the fruit in a form and being able to modify the "name" and "color" attributes.

I don't understand why, but when I click the "modify" button, the form is being displayed but the properties of the fruits that I clicked are not.

Here is the code:

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fruit/modify", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String modifyFruit( @RequestParam("id") int id, ModelMap model) {
        Fruit fruit = fruitManager.getFruitById(id);
        model.addAttribute("fruit", fruit);
        return "redirect:/modifyfruit";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/modifyfruit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showAddForm(@ModelAttribute("fruit") Fruit fruit, ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("fruit", fruit);
        return "/secure/modifyfruit";
    }
```

Here is the modify button that I am displaying next to each fruit in my list:

```
<td>
    <c:url var="modifyUrl" value="/fruit/modify.html"/>    
    <form id="${fruitForm}" action="${modifyUrl}" method="POST">
        <input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" value="${fruit.id}"/>
        <input type="submit" value="modify"/>
    </form>
</td>
```

Here is the modifyfruit.jsp that I am using to display the form that I want to populate:

```
<body>
    <form:form method="post" commandName="fruit">
        <table width="95%" bgcolor="f8f8ff" border="0" cellspacing="0"
            cellpadding="5">
            <tr>
                <td align="right">Name:</td>
                <td><form:input path="title" value="${fruit.name}"/></td>   
            </tr>
<tr>
                <td align="right">Color:</td>
                <td><form:input path="color" value="${fruit.color}"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" align="center" value="Post Ad">
    </form:form>

</body>
```

Comment: Maybe because you are using redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your redirect is simply going to that new URL without any request params being added. Therefore your fruit ID is being discarded, which is why nothing gets displayed.

The redirect seems pointless - why not return the same view name string as the GET version instead?

To redirect with the params, try:

```
return "redirect:/modifyfruit?id=" + id;
```

EDIT: just noticed you have added the Fruit to the model - this does not get transferred in a redirect and wouldn't work anyway.